# Minimum access required for Visual Studio 2010 on Windows Server 2008

Tags: development, permissions, sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio, windows-server

Hi we are trying to set up a SharePoint development environment for multiple developers on Windows 2008 server, we do not want to give the developers admin rights to the servers, does anyone know the minimum rights!they need, right now if they are not admins they receive this error, when trying to create a new project, although it does create the folder for the project it gets stuck on this error.

***"This task requires the application to have elevated permissions"***

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I cannot provide an answer to your question, however I would strongly encourage you to have each developer develop on his/her own machine in a virtual environment.

Here's a link to get you started: http://geekswithblogs.net/manesh/archive/2010/05/28/building-the-ultimate-sharepoint-2010-development-environment.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Even though the [Requirements for Developing SharePoint Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231582.aspx) doesn't state it clearly for server operating systems I'm pretty sure that you similar to Vista/Windows 7 need to run as administrator to use the SharePoint tools

And please don't try to let them share the same server.

Answer (score 1):

I'll echo those who have commented before me that it's not really practical for developers to be sharing a server, nor using actual dev or prod hardware. Typically, developers run a local VM or some other form of a personal development environment with a configuration as close to prod as possible (ie: all service applications, search, etc. configured).

As for the actual question about Visual Studio rights. If you intend to use any of the quick-deploy tools, then Visual Studio needs the ability to reset IIS and deploy solutions to your environment. In that scenario, the user needs to be a farm administrator and local administrator (unless you have otherwise granted the ability for that user to do IIS resets and such, which normally requires local administrator).